# Which values of $\alpha$ make this integral convergent?

Tags: integration, summation

I'm facing problems figuring out which values of $\alpha$ makes
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^{10}x^{j}\right)
^{-\left(n +1\right)/10}\,\frac{-n + 1}{10}\,x^{\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
convergent. The problem also states that $n>0$ and $\alpha$ is a real number.

I tried substituting the summation with the geometric series formula but I cannot figure out how to deal with the $n$.

Comment: What is $i$ referring to, the imaginary unit?

Comment: It is the index for summation, my bad

Comment: Yes, n is a positive variable

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{j=1}^{10} x^j = x^{10} + \text{ lower order terms}$

Comment: @Integrand I think it's $x^{10}$ plus lower order terms, isn't it?

Comment: For what values of $\beta$ is $\int_1^\infty x^\beta\,\mathrm{d}x$ convergent?

Comment: What if  extract degree for $x$ in $\infty$ neighbourhood ?

Answer (score 1):

The power of $x$ in each part of the integral must be less than $-1$ for the integral to converge. The powers are $$j\frac{-n+1}{10}+\alpha$$ for $j$ from $1$ to $10$

When $\frac{-n+1}{10}$ is positive, the power will be greatest at $j=10$, therefore $$-n+1+\alpha<-1$$$$\alpha<n-2$$

When $\frac{-n+1}{10}$ is negative, the power will be greatest at $j=1$, therefore $$\frac{-n+1}{10}+\alpha<-1$$$$\alpha<\frac{n-11}{10}$$